# Call to undefined method Modules\User\Services\web\facade\WebAuth::loginUsername()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, throttling

I am using laravel `ThrottlesLogins` in my custom facade class as trait. I am using

```
if($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request))
    return $this->ThrottleActions($request);
```

in my login method, but why I am facing the subject error

```
Call to undefined method Modules\User\Services\web\facade\WebAuth::loginUsername()
```

However on local its working fine. But when I update code online server. I am facing this error. 
This method `loginUsername()` already exist in `ThrottlesLogins` trait.

Comment: You only use phasers in star trek ;-)

Comment: try composer dump-autolaod

Comment: I already used compser autoloader, even I have used php artisan optimize.

Comment: Still I am having the issue, Any help?